# Reliability of the boost::numeric::ublas::matrix LU inversion method

Tags: c++, matrix, boost

**My Problem :** inverse squared matrices of doubles numbers of size 30*30 (or around this size).

I started coding in C++ a LU decomposition method, then I discovered the existence of the librairie boost::numeric::ublas::matrix. Therefore to spare me rewriting everything I used some functions of this librairie, namely in this very order lu_factorize() then lu_substitute() to retrieve the inverse.

I hand-checked the reliability of my inversing function (which again, only use the 2 aforementioned boost functions) comparing the results with simple squared matrices (size 3 or 4) and the results are satisfying so far.

Now taking a (30,30) matrix "A" and inversing it "A^-1", the product "A*A^-1" returns me a matrix with 1 on the diagonale and everywhere else some very small numbers, here's a snippet :

```
 1         -1.5e-16  -5.1e-20  2.4e-19  
 0         1         0         -5.4e-20  
 1.1e-16   1.1e-16   1         -1.4e-19  
 6.9e-17   0         -3.3e-17  1
```

I cannot tell if these numbers (out of the main diagonale) are made up by the matrix librairie trying to approximate 0 or if they issued from the LU decomposition ...

**My question :** Have you ever used boost ublas with this issue ? Is this librairie still reliable or outdated ? Is there any way to access the source code of these algorithm ?

Thanks in advance

Using C++11, gcc/8.2.0 and boost/1.76.0.

Comment: For `float` something close to `10^-38` would be a zero approximation for `double` it's about `10^-308` (see: [Fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) ).  So even for float 18 order of magnitude away from approx `0` is too much. Full source for Boost is available follow the development link to github https://www.boost.org/

Comment: Addendum unless the test data contains values deliberately chosen (or coincidently) to be numerically unstable.

Comment: Well I don't know what are "unstable" values and I'm not sure these exists in such a problem, but I may formulate my question as follow : when one inverse a matrix, it will most probably gives you floating numbers everywhere (except if you are at school where your inverse matrices will only contain integers !). Now that you have an approximated inversed matrix, **how can one verify it is indeed the very inverse** ? It is evident that the result of A*A^-1 won't yield exactly the identity matrix since A^-1 is approximated ...

Comment: Unstable means expression like, for example: adding or subtracting a very small value from a very large value such that the large value remains unchanged (this is due to the limitations floating point representation in a computer); therefore causing convergent formula never to converge.  There are many examples of this and Computer Science - Numerical Methods has a significant body of work on this subject. There are also libraries for infinite rational numerical methods.